# Bash script to calculate within a CSV

Tags: bash, awk, csv

This is my CSV File:

```
Number;Reference;EANNumber;Manufacturer;Price_B2B;Price_B2B_Dis;Price_B2B_DisPer;Price_B2B_DisAmount;Price_B2C_exVAT;Price_B2C_inVAT
2330113;BP3141;1,31304E+11;APC;13;13;0;0;0;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
1402141;A51U;8,84333E+11;HP;2;2;0;0;0;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
1450121;LC125XLC;4,34444E+12;Brother;11,4;11,4;0;0;0;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
5431414;YEG-00431;343434315;Msoft;11,1;11,1;0;0;31,45;41,31;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
5533314;QQC-08323;8,85341E+11;Microsoft;522,23;522,23;0;0;0;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3140025;30MB0SY0-M0EAY0;1,4123E+12;Asus;11,33;11,33;0;0;0;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
1452531;R18-05435;3,33334E+12;Microsoft;24;24;0;0;1,8;1,33;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
4480158;M28-00002;;Meyss;54,22;54,22;0;0;11,13;31,13;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
2310152;AC2T0E;;HP;52;52;0;0;0;0;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I want to execute the following formula via bash script:

> =WHEN(I2=0;E2*1,2;I2)

price should be displayed in column x

can you do that with awk or gawk? I've tried but can't get any further.

I want to read a CSV file and run the calculation within the CSV file.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001 as a starting point.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to do what [@Cyrus requested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/738573/bash-script-to-calculate-within-a-csv#comment1402109_738573) and add your attempt to solve the problem yourself then I expect we can help you.

Comment: Don't add information in comments where it cant be formatted and could be missed - **[edit] your question** to include all relevant information. Remember to include textual sample input/output as requested along with your attempted code so we have something we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: Please explain the formula.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you reformulate the formula in terms of the actual names of the fields present on the first line of the data? What is "column `x`"? What does the `WHEN` function(?) do? What is the expected output given the example data that you show?

Comment: You say you want to implement `=WHEN(I2=0;E2*1,2;I2)` which I assume is some kind of Excel formula but what does it mean and which column names in your input are you referring to and what should it's output be? You say `price should be displayed in column x` but there is no column `x` in your sample input. Please [edit] your question to provide the still missing expected output we've been asking for and your attempt to solve the problem yourself (the awk script you had previously posted in a now-deleted comment by mistake). Make it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be assuming that you want is a new field called `x` with the value from the `Price_B2C_exVAT` field, unless that value is zero in which case you want 1.2 times the value in the `Price_B2B` field.

The following reads the input as a "ragged" CSV file with headers ("ragged" as there are a varying number of fields in the records) and first uses the `remove-empty-columns` subcommand to remove empty columns.  It then creates the new field `x` in each record using the formula given.

We can calculate the value for the new field with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) like so:

```bash
mlr --csv --fs ';' --ragged \
    remove-empty-columns then \
    put '$x = $Price_B2C_exVAT; $x == 0 { $x = 1.2*$Price_B2B }' file.csv
```

This would have worked well if your floating point values had used `.` as the decimal point rather than `,`.  Instead, we convert the `Price_B2B` value from a string to a floating point value by simply replacing the comma with a dot:

```bash
mlr --csv --fs ';' --ragged \
    remove-empty-columns then \
    put '$x = $Price_B2C_exVAT; $x == 0 { $x = 1.2*float(ssub(string($Price_B2B),",",".")) }' file.csv
```

To convert the floating point values into strings that use commas in place of dots, we do the reverse to `x` to what we did to `Price_B2B`:

```bash
mlr --csv --fs ';' --ragged \
    remove-empty-columns then \
    put '
        $x = $Price_B2C_exVAT;
        $x == 0 {
            $x = 1.2*float(ssub(string($Price_B2B), ",", "."));
            $x = ssub(string($x), ".", ",");
        }' file.csv
```

Or, with `put -S` to stop Miller from inferring the type of the data in the fields and leaving it as strings (this gets rid of the need to explicitly convert `Price_B2B` to a string in the case where it's zero):

```bash
mlr --csv --fs ';' --ragged \
    remove-empty-columns then \
    put -S '
        $x = $Price_B2C_exVAT;
        $x == "0" {
            $x = 1.2*float(ssub($Price_B2B, ",", "."));
            $x = ssub(string($x), ".", ",");
        }' file.csv
```

The result, using the example from the question (the `x` field is added to the end of the list of fields):

```
Number;Reference;EANNumber;Manufacturer;Price_B2B;Price_B2B_Dis;Price_B2B_DisPer;Price_B2B_DisAmount;Price_B2C_exVAT;Price_B2C_inVAT;x
2330113;BP3141;1,31304E+11;APC;13;13;0;0;0;0;15,600000
1402141;A51U;8,84333E+11;HP;2;2;0;0;0;0;2,400000
1450121;LC125XLC;4,34444E+12;Brother;11,4;11,4;0;0;0;0;13,680000
5431414;YEG-00431;343434315;Msoft;11,1;11,1;0;0;31,45;41,31;31,45
5533314;QQC-08323;8,85341E+11;Microsoft;522,23;522,23;0;0;0;0;626,676000
3140025;30MB0SY0-M0EAY0;1,4123E+12;Asus;11,33;11,33;0;0;0;0;13,596000
1452531;R18-05435;3,33334E+12;Microsoft;24;24;0;0;1,8;1,33;1,8
4480158;M28-00002;;Meyss;54,22;54,22;0;0;11,13;31,13;11,13
2310152;AC2T0E;;HP;52;52;0;0;0;0;62,400000
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much Unfortunately I get the table with a comma.
The 2nd script with the conversion works great. However, the result of the calculation is still output with a point, without calculation with a comma.
Is it always possible to display the result with a comma?

Comment: @dima1002 See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For simple CSVs, you should be able to get away with `awk`. In a locale that uses `,` as the decimal radix character:

```bash
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' '
  {print $0, NR == 1 ? "x" : $9 ? $9 : $5 * 1.2}' < file.csv
```

Would add an extra field:

- on the first line (`NR == 1`), `x`
- on other lines:

  - if `$9` (the 9<sup>th</sup> field) is non 0, `$9`
  - else the 5<sup>th</sup> field multiplied by 1.2.

To change the format of floating point number, set the `CONVFMT` variable (doesn't affect integers) like with `-v CONVFMT=%.2f` and for numerical conversion for instance by adding 0+ in front of the second `$9`, or better as it would affect integers as well:

```bash
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' '
  {print $0, NR == 1 ? "x" : sprintf("%.2f", $9 ? $9 : $5 * 1.2)}' < file.csv
```

The `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` is for GNU `awk` which doesn't honour the locale's decimal radix without it.

Comment: Where is the output? In the Excel spreadsheet? If yes, where?